# SwiftUI DisclosureGroup overlaps when expanded

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a grid of DisclosureGroup enclosed in a 2 column LazyVGrid. The problem I am having is that when I expand the DisclosureGroup it overlaps the Text below the group. Is there a way to fix the overlap? Ideally, I would like the DisclosureGroupView (shown below) to push everything down.

I tried to use zIndex on the DisclosureGroup but it does not look good. It basically expands the entire grid which encloses the DisclosureGroup view.

Appreciate very much for any direction to fix this issue!

Here is what I have so far:

DisclosureGroupView:

```
struct DisclosureGroupView: View {
    var groups: [String: [String]]
    @State private var isExpanded: [String: Bool]
    @State private var selectedItems = [String: Set<String>]()
    @State private var isTitleChecked: [String: Bool]
    
    init(groups: [String: [String]]) {
        self.groups = groups
        _isExpanded = State(initialValue: groups.reduce(into: [String: Bool](), { result, group in
            result[group.key] = false
        }))
        _isTitleChecked = State(initialValue: groups.reduce(into: [String: Bool](), {result, group in
            result[group.key] = false
        }))
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            let ncols = 2
            let width = geo.size.width / CGFloat(ncols)
            let layout = Array(repeating: GridItem(.fixed(width), spacing: 5), count: ncols)
            LazyVGrid(columns: layout, alignment: .leading) {
                ForEach(groups.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { title in
                    self.disclosureGroup(title: title, items: groups[title, default: [String]()])
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func disclosureGroup(title: String, items: [String]) -> some View {
        let expanded = Binding<Bool>(get: {isExpanded[title]!}, set: {isExpanded[title] = $0})
        return DisclosureGroup(title, isExpanded: expanded) {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    ForEach(Array(items.enumerated()), id: \.1.hashValue) { index, item in
                        Text(item)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    }
                }
                .zIndex(1.0)
            }
            .frame(height: 60)
        }
        .font(.body)
        .frame(width: 110)
        .accentColor(.white)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .padding(5)
        .background(Color(UIColor.systemBlue))
        .cornerRadius(8.0)
    }
}
```

ContentView to use the above view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
            Text("Disclosure Groups")
            let groups: [String: [String]] = ["R1C1" : ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"],
                                              "R1C2" : ["item 3", "item 4", "item 6", "item 7"],
                                              "R2C1" : ["item 5", "item 6"],
                                              "R2C2" : ["item 7", "item 8"]]
            DisclosureGroupView(groups: groups)
                .frame(height: 80)
            Text("More Text here that is long")
                .padding()
            Text("Some More Text even wider than the first one")
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I am getting:
[image]

Comment: You're using a fixed height `.frame(height: 80)`...

Comment: If I don't use a fixed height, the DisclosureGroup uses the entire screen. Also, the number of items can vary! Without a height parameter, there will be a gap between DisclosureGroupView and the Text below it

Answer (score 0):

[StackOverFlow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3agn.png)

The height is fixed because of the GeometryReader. I modified it by passing the width.

```swift
//
//  SwiftUIView.swift
//  asdadd
//
//  Created by USER on 2021/08/04.
//

import SwiftUI

struct DisclosureGroupView: View {
    var groups: [String: [String]]
    var width: CGFloat
    @State private var isExpanded: [String: Bool]
    @State private var selectedItems = [String: Set<String>]()
    @State private var isTitleChecked: [String: Bool]
    
    init(groups: [String: [String]], width: CGFloat) {
        self.groups = groups
        self.width = width
        _isExpanded = State(initialValue: groups.reduce(into: [String: Bool](), { result, group in
            result[group.key] = false
        }))
        _isTitleChecked = State(initialValue: groups.reduce(into: [String: Bool](), {result, group in
            result[group.key] = false
        }))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
//        GeometryReader { geo in
            let ncols = 2
            let width = width / CGFloat(ncols)
            let layout = Array(repeating: GridItem(.fixed(width), spacing: 5), count: ncols)
            
            LazyVGrid(columns: layout, alignment: .leading) {
                ForEach(groups.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { title in
                    self.disclosureGroup(title: title, items: groups[title, default: [String]()])
                }
            }
            .border(Color.red)
//        }
    }
    
    
    private func disclosureGroup(title: String, items: [String]) -> some View {
        let expanded = Binding<Bool>(get: {isExpanded[title]!}, set: {isExpanded[title] = $0})
        return DisclosureGroup(title, isExpanded: expanded) {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    ForEach(Array(items.enumerated()), id: \.1.hashValue) { index, item in
                        Text(item)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        
                    }
                }
                .zIndex(1.0)
            }
        }
        .font(.body)
        .frame(width: 110)
        .accentColor(.white)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .padding(5)
        .background(Color(UIColor.systemBlue))
        .cornerRadius(8.0)
    }
}

struct ContentView2: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
                Text("Disclosure Groups")
                
                let groups: [String: [String]] = ["R1C1" : ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"],
                                                  "R1C2" : ["item 3", "item 4", "item 6", "item 7"],
                                                  "R2C1" : ["item 5", "item 6"],
                                                  "R2C2" : ["item 7", "item 8"]]
                DisclosureGroupView(groups: groups, width: geometry.size.width)
                //                    .frame(height: 80)
                Text("More Text here that is long")
                    .padding()
                Text("Some More Text even wider than the first one")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView2()
    }
}
```

I don't know if VStack's alignment doesn't work.

I moved it to the center using position.

```swift
GeometryReader { geometry in
    VStack(spacing: 10) {
        Text("Disclosure Groups")
        
        let groups: [String: [String]] = ["R1C1" : ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"],
                                          "R1C2" : ["item 3", "item 4", "item 6", "item 7"],
                                          "R2C1" : ["item 5", "item 6"],
                                          "R2C2" : ["item 7", "item 8"]]
        DisclosureGroupView(groups: groups, width: geometry.size.width)
        //                    .frame(height: 80)
        Text("More Text here that is long")
            .padding()
        Text("Some More Text even wider than the first one")
    }
    .position(x: geometry.frame(in:.local).midX,
              y: geometry.frame(in:.local).midY)
}
```